# Restrict Access to Wordpress pages by Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, wordpress

How do I restrict access to certain pages? I intend for users to login using only Facebook login. 
I want to allow access to some pages without users needing to log in and a few pages to require users to log in using Facebook connect before being able to access the content.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have users created, restrict access control to posts and pages via one of the many plugin options. example

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Comment: Thanks! I used another plugin, but it worked as well

Comment: Cool! yeah there are a ton out there.